# Extremum problem (cylinder cut from frustum of cone) from Apostol "Calculus" Volume 1

Tags: calculus

Im having trouble solving the following problem from Apostol "Calculus" Volume I (Section 4.21, # 24) (PS; this is not a homework assignment: I'm doing this out of interest). The problem as stated is:

"A log 12 feet long has the shape of a frustum of a right circular cone with diameters 4 feet and (4+h) feet at its ends, where h >= 0. Determine, as a function of h, the volume of the largest right circular cylinder that can be cut from the log, if it's axis coincides with that of the log."

My thoughts so far:

1. We have to consider two cases.

   - The Height of the cylinder is the same as the height of the frustum;
     and
   - The Height of the cylinder is not the same as the height of the frustum
2. As far as I can see, we are focusing on varying the height of the
   cylinder, so we would need to find a constraint which defines H (the
   height of the cylinder) in terms of h (defined in the original
   question)
3. Once we obtained the constraint defined in point 2, we substitute it into the formula for the volume of a cylinder (V) , Obtain dV/dh and set it to 0 and determine the relative maximum.
4. the case where the height of the cylinder is the same as the height if the frustum is easy (in part);

   v =\pi*4*12 = 48\pi

   this is indeed part of the answer though it insists that that 0<=h < 2 (I don't know how to confirm the constraint)
5. I seem to unable to proceed from here
6. The answer defined in Apostol is:
   V = 48/pi for 0<=h<2; V = 4\pi(4+h)^3/(9h), h >= 2

so what I am asking is:

1. Am I on the right tack
2. If so, any thoughts on where to proceed in finding the constraint and proceeding with this problem

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**.  I think generally you are on the right track.

1. I don't think you need to consider the two separate cases, it should all work out.  See also point 3.
2. Draw a carefully labelled diagram and use similar triangles.  You may need to extend the frustum of a cone to show the complete cone.
3. To find the maximum you need to not only find where $dV/dH$ is zero but also consider the endpoints of the interval, that is, the cases $H=0$ and $H=h$.  **NB** that was $dV/dH$ not $dV/dh$.  Probably, you will find that for certain values of $h$ the maximum occurs when $dV/dH=0$ and for others it occurs when $H=h$.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David. If I am interpreting you correctly I get the following:

Comment: Start again. (1) using the similar triangle argument I get: 12/(h/2) = H (ie The total height of the cone)/(2+h/2). This leads to H = 12 +48/h . If I now let H = height of the cylinder, I can obtain (from another similar triangle argument) (12+48/h)/(2+h/2) = (2+h/2 -r(ie cylinder radius))/ H which leads to H = (48/h + 12 - 24r/h) . To me your statement is implying that that we should be calculating dV/dh and not dV/dH. Please excuse my ignorance on this, but I cannot help wondering if Im overthinking the problem at this point?

Comment: I wouldn't say you are overthinking it, but there are a couple of mistakes.  First, if I read the question correctly, $12$ is the height of the frustum, not the total height of the cone.  You will have to figure out the total height by similar triangles.  Remember that $h$ is not a variable, it will be a particular number even though it is not specified in the question.  The unknown height of the maximal cylinder is $H$, so you definitely need $dV/dH$.

Comment: Suggestion: perhaps you should try the problem first with definite values of $h$.  Try $h=4$, then try $h=1$, then see if you can do it for an unspecified $h$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and advice. I realised that as the cylinder was changing in its radius (r) and its height (H), I needed to define r in terms of H and substitute this into the formula for the Volume. Then I can derive dV/dH and thus get the correct answer. Like most mathematical problems, the answer is obvious when you see it :-) Thanks again for all your help